# Change NavigationView items when user is logged

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

My app's main activity has a navigation drawer, instantiated in the XML in this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/application_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Now, the menu entry for the navigation drawer is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
        android:title="@string/login"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/terms"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:title="@string/terms_and_conditions_menu"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:title="@string/info_hotelsclick"/>
</group>
```

What I'd like to do is to change the first item (and possibly the others as well) dynamically under some conditions. For instance, I'd like to change the "Login" entry with a "logout" one once the user has logged in ;-)

How can I achieve that? I managed to add an item to the Drawer in this way

```
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add("Test");
```

but it doesn't sound that good to me, I'm pretty sure there must be a cleaner way.

...but does it?

Comment: call the method to setup drawer again with update values.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I thing the best approach to this is to include all your items in the menu and the change their visibility.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
    android:title="@string/login"
    android:visible="true" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    android:visible="false" />
```

then

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);
```

You can also do this with whole groups of items

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:visible="false">
    ...
</group>
```

and

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_1, true)
```

Comment: it works but the space remails as such, any idea as how to remove the space?

Comment: Great answer! I think there is few practical information about NavigationView.

Comment: Use navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisibility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) instead so the invisible UI element doesnt take the space.

Comment: What @JoakimSandqvist wrote is incorrect. You cannot call `setVisibility` because findItem doesn't return a view

Comment: Why remove group or clear does not works in dynamic updating mode. I can not dynamically remove items and add new items. My fragment should re create to show.

Answer (score 62):

Simple solution:
Add two xml files in menu directory:

1. `navigation_with_login.xml` Navigation Menu for logged in users

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
               android:title="Import" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
               android:title="Gallery" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
               android:title="Slideshow" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_login"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_login"
               android:title="Login" />
       </group>


   </menu>
   ```
2. `navigation_with_logout.xml`  Navigation Menu for default user:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
               android:title="Import" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
               android:title="Gallery" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
               android:title="Slideshow" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_logout"
               android:title="Logout" />
       </group>

   </menu>
   ```

Now you can change `NavigationView` items,just write few lines of code.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

if(islogin)
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation_with_login);
    } else
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation_with_logout);
    }
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: This looks more elegant to me, specially considering that in the other solution the hidden items still take up space, apparently (didn't test it myself but the comments said so).

Comment: Thanks  João Josézinho

Comment: @manish jain: Thank you very much. You solved my problem related, having 2 drawers list for different logins in app.

Comment: bad approach, what if i need two items to change and one of them has 3 states. so I would need 6 menus lol

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since using visibility won't be efficient

Comment: I have one question, when using this approach and when clicking on the menu, the menu changes in the instance I click on the menu, so as a user I see the change, I want this to happen before the menu appears, so the user does not see the changes.
Thanks!

Comment: @Mikhail It is not a bad approach. For most of the cases this will be a good solution. There are exceptions of course. One solution will never fit all the problem. Your scenario will be one of the exceptional case. That will have to be worked differently. Cases where you need to have different menu when user is logged in and logged out, this is a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

**Frst get the navigationmenu**

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
```

**To add the menu dynamically**

```
 if(loggedOut){
        menu.add(R.id.submenu_others, R.id.action_logout, Menu.NONE, "logout");
}
```

> Here is menu.add(groupId, menuItemId, orderOfMenu, menuItem text)

```
     if(loggedIn){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_logout);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it done, try this when you need to change the title:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.yourItemId).setTitle("my title");
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: This would work as well, of course, but I'd also need to change the action related and the icon... I'd rather use the show/hide solution that Lamorak provided below. Thank you anyway! :-)