# Navigation Drawer Refreshed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-sharedpreferences

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611198/5737774) answer on SO, which is titled as:

**Change NavigationView items when user is logged**

The code works fine but the content of `NavigationView` change when I restart the app. I want the content to be changed after I click Login or LogOut `item menus`

This is my code in `onCreate()` method:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        if(islogin())
        {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear();
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer1);
        } else
        {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear();
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer2);
        }
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        toggle.syncState();
```

and here is the `islogin()` method:

```
    public boolean islogin(){
// Retrieve data from preference:
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserLoginData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = prefs.getString("username",   null);
        if (username == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Any help would greatly appreciated! Thank You

Note: Though this question seems duplicate of some, but its just the title, contents are entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I didn't get answer, I am posting my solution here.
I did solve it a very simple logic and its working very great.

**Step 1:**

I first initialize `Toolbar toolbar;` globally above class.

**Step 2:**

Then I just create a simple method called: `myDrawer()` and wrap all my Drawer code inside it. Like this:

```
public void myDrawer(){

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    if(islogin())
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer2);
    } else
    {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
    }
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toggle.syncState();

}
```

Now I have hands over the Navigation and I can do anything with it, Like Refreshing and Calling again etc.

**Step 3:**

I am calling the method in Main Activity i-e: `OnCreate`

```
myDrawer();
```

**Step 4:**

And I am calling it every time I do logic of `Signin` and `SignOut`.

Wow! It's working like a charm.

**PS:** Just for the info purpose, Here is my `onNavigationItemSelected`, where I can handle Click Events:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent;
        if (id == R.id.nav_item_item1) {

            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeClass1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item_item2) {
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeClass2.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_item_logout) {
            // my other logic for signout
               myDrawer();

        } 

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

**Credits:**

[User: manish jain Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611198/5737774)